# What stops the number of unauthenticated/guest identities spiralling out of control?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Each time a "guest" (unauthenticated) user is used with Cognito, a new *identity* is created. These soon pile up and I have over 100 of them just from executing my own experiments.

Example code:

```
// We're not providing specific login details from an IDP,
// so will be granted access as a guest user
AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
    IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId
});

// Make the actual REST API call to get guest user credentials.
AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err){
    if (err) {
        //...
    }
    else {
        //...
    }
});
```

- Is there anything I should know about that is considered best practice for dealing with guest user identities?
- Should I delete them somehow with a cron job or similar?
- Is there a *time to idle* setting somewhere that I haven't discovered, so that they are deleted/removed/purged automatically?
- Should I be using one, single guest identity shared between all of the guests?

Sorry if this sounds vague, I'm still getting to grips with Cognito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there a time to idle setting somewhere that I haven't discovered, so that they are deleted/removed/purged automatically?**
Cognito doesn't automatically clear ids for you.

**Should I delete them somehow with a cron job or similar?**
You can delete identities, Cognito does expose an API to do so, but Cognito federated identities is free to use. You won't be charged anything if you keep them around.

**Should I be using one, single guest identity shared between all of the guests?**
If you aren't using the identity id to key data somewhere or scope access (e.g. keys in Dynamo, prefixes in S3...etc.) you could share the guest id, but we don't recommend doing so. The specifics depend on your use case, but the recommended approach is to keep one id per user to allow scoping of credentials, usage tracing...etc.

**Is there anything I should know about that is considered best practice for dealing with guest user identities?**
If you add an authentication provider to your pool and an unauthenticated id signs in, that unauthenticated id will disappear and become an authenticated one. Again, though, they are free to use. If you're rapidly testing and want to have only new data visible, the API to delete identities makes sense as a way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I propose, generate a UUID or GUID using aws lambda or sme service of yours and send that to the invitee, as invite code, you can put the cognito API negotiation code behind API gateway, the first interaction with the api is to validate invitecode is valid (you generated and cached it in dynamo db or some persistent store). and create the cognito id and send that to user along with the temp creds, rest of the API Gateway apis you expose will require the authentication , id, secret and session, that you send after validating the first invite.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, unfortunately I don't understand it. There's a lot there which could be broken down into pieces and expanded further — I just can't comprehend it as it is. My first question would be, where do invites fit into this? My question was about guest users, they don't have invites, they just use the website *without* logging in or doing anything special.